# Why cant first and last be used?

Tags: java, static, printf

Hey guys I cant run due to the private strings "first" and "last" not being "used."

Any idea why to what is causing the problem? thanks!

```
public class Bananas{

    private String first;
    private String last;
    private static int members = 0;

    public Bananas(String fn, String ln){
        first = fn;
        last = ln;
        members++;

        System.out.printf("Constructor for %s %s, members in the club: %d\n", members);
    }
}
```

**Separate classes**

```
public class clasone {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Bananas member1 = new Bananas ("Ted","O'Shea");
        Bananas member2 = new Bananas ("John","Wayne");
        Bananas member3 = new Bananas ("Hope","Go");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the error message you're getting?

Comment: It's probably just a warning, not a compilation error.  The code's not useful because there's no way to get information out of your class.

Comment: error "Contructor for 1 Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%s'
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.PrintStream.format(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.PrintStream.printf(Unknown Source)
 at Main.<init>(Main.java:13)
 at clasone.main(clasone.java:4)
"

Comment: That's nothing to do with Strings not being used... Please edit your question to include the actual error!

Comment: but its not using the first or last Strings?

Comment: @KyleMcCann, indeed; there are other things wrong with it as well, but none of them are the cause of the error you've added above.

Comment: @KyleMcCann it's not using them because you didn't include them in your code for the `printf` line.

Comment: *"but its not using the first or last Strings?"* - That is correct!  It isn't!  Look at the parameters you passed to `printf`!

Comment: Kyle - rule number #1 - read the error message.  rule #2 - read the code that you wrote.  In this case, if the compiler says that you didn't use X but you think you did, read the code where you think you used X to make sure that you really did.

Comment: Kyle - rule number #3 - compiler error or warnings are not wrong, and neither are exception messages.  99.9% of the tine they tell the truth.  It is up to you to understand what they say.  Doubting them is futile.  (The other 0.1%, you have managed to confuse the compiler.  It is still telling the truth, but in a confused way.)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a compilation error, it's a runtime error. As it states, your `printf` formatting is incorrect - it expects three arguments (two strings and an int) while you're only passing onw (`members`). From the context, I assume you meant to pass `first` and `last` there too:

```
System.out.printf("Constructor for %s %s, members in the club: %d\n", 
                   first, last, members);
// -- Here  -------^------^
```

Comment: Thank you sorry for the noob question!

Answer (score 1):

your error is in this line :

```
 System.out.printf("Constructor for %s %s, members in the club: %d\n", members);
```

change it like this :

```
System.out.printf("Constructor for %s %s, members in the club: %d\n", first, last, members);
```

The message `the private strings "first" and "last" not being "used."`| is a warning and not an error.

The error `"Contructor for 1 Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException:` is a runtime error and not a compilation error. It's related to missing argumennts in `printf` method witch expected 3 arguments `String, String, Number` because in your message you have `%s %s %d`.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because you have place holders in your `String` format for which there is no corresponding value, indeed you have twice `%s` and once `%d` which means that it expects two arguments to be converted into a `String` and an integer or a long.

Try this instead:

```
System.out.printf(
    "Constructor for %s %s, members in the club: %d\n", first, last, members
);
```

More details about a `Formatter` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

**NB:** You can replace `\n` in your `String` format with `%n` for the same result as next:

```
System.out.printf(
    "Constructor for %s %s, members in the club: %d%n", first, last, members
);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Contructor for 1 Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%s'

This is a runtime error , not a compile time error. It means you have three values in your format, but you only provided one.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is into below line:

```
System.out.printf("Constructor for %s %s, members in the club: %d\n", members);
```

Bcause you are using two format specifier for String and one for int into printf statement, so you must have to pass three value for respective format specifier, Like this:

```
System.out.printf("Constructor for %s %s, members in the club: %d\n", first,last,members);
```

Or Remove format specifier if you want to use only members into printf statement, so change like that :

```
System.out.printf("Constructor for the members in the club: %d\n", members);
```